# Programmatically return Partial View with correct index

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a view that is rendering **Person** objects in a list called **People** in a table with dynamic rows. I render it like so in the HTML:

```
<partial name="_People" for="Model.People[i]" />
```

With *i* being the index in the for loop.

So it then goes and renders a partial view with the correct input names so I can bind back to it. Like so:

```
<input name="People[0].Name" ...
<input name="People[0].PhoneNumber" ...
```

I want to call back to my razor model to render a new row programmatically and have it return a row with the correct index. So say there are already 7 rows in the table, I hit a button and it returns a Partial View with my row inputs with the correct index of 8 in their names. I can then append this row to the table with javascript. So just wondering if there is a programmatic equivalent to

```
<partial name="_People" for="Model.People[8]" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You can set the HTML Field Prefix in the view data template info.

Like so:

```
int index = 8;
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.format("People[{0}], index)";
```